# Leftside limit of the Distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $(\Omega,\mathrm{P})$ be a probabilty space and $X$ be a random variable.
Why is $\lim\limits_{s \uparrow t}\mathrm{P}(X < s)= \mathrm{P}(X \leq t)$?
I first thought that this follows from the continuity from below, but this doesn't works. If I consider $x_n \to t $ with $x_n < t$ then $x_n$ can also decreasing in some points...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a monotonically increasing function $F$  we can write $\sup \{F(y): y<x\}=\lim_{ y \uparrow x}F(x)=\lim F(x_n)$  where $x_n$ is any sequence incresaing to $x$. Hence $\lim_{s\uparrow t} P(X<s)$ is same as $\lim P(X<t-\frac 1  n)=P(X \leq t)$.